# Very basic web scraping query for you fine folk

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

Just working on a small project for which I'd like to web scrape the price of a particular item. I've never done this before and I'm having difficulty using a few methods.

This is the webpage in question:
https://www.made.com/keira-office-chair-cloud-grey-and-copper

and this is the element in question:

```
<div class="ProductPrice__PriceWrapper-rtg8id-0 guIZZV"><span class="ProductPrice__Price-rtg8id-1 jYfukd">£149</span><div></div><div></div></div>    <span class="ProductPrice__Price-rtg8id-1 jYfukd">£149</span><div></div><div></div>
```

The code I am trying is as follows:

```
import requests, bs4

URL = 'https://www.made.com/keira-office-chair-cloud-grey-and-copper'
page = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
page.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('ProductPrice__Price-rtg8id-1 jYfukd').get_text()
print(price)
```

The error I receive is: 
`ttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

I had a look around it appears an easier method of doing what I am attempting is to use a CSS selector, however I have tried that (perhaps incorrectly) and when I run my script, it just returns '[]'.

Could somebody kindly explain what I am doing wrong, or what I should be looking for?

Comment: if im not mistaken, you are not running any of the javascript on the page, so content that is loaded dynamically will simply not be in your request. you will need to use something that actually rendered the page like `selenium`. [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/) is a tutorial on this sort of thing i just found

Answer (score 2):

```
page = requests.get('https://www.made.com/keira-office-chair-cloud-grey-and-copper',headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', attrs={"class":"ProductPrice__Price-rtg8id-1"}).get_text()
print(price)
```

If you want to check if its loaded in dynamically, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to check the page source and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for the string you want to find. This is the same data as python requests gets.

This site will be a bit harder to scrape since it has [Distil bot blocking.](https://www.distilnetworks.com/block-bot-detection/) I don't really have experience with bypassing that, though.
The POC I posted should work if you're not blocked by the site. You can check this by printing out the soup/source and searching for a `distilIdentificationBlock` div.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed blocked! I tried another website (Tesco.co.uk) and managed to scrape the price fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that from the document you find there is no attribute "ProductPrice__Price-rtg8id-1 jYfukd"
Instead, in order for you to see what you are actually getting you can print the output of the document received and then start scraping from there.

Here's an example and a valid get from the document you are receiving:

```
import requests
import bs4
url =  "https://www.made.com/keira-office-chair-cloud-grey-and-copper"
page = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
page.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(id="distilIdentificationBlock")
print(price)
print(soup)
```

here's the output:

```
<div id="distilIdentificationBlock"> </div> <!--output of the soup.find-->
```

the code below is the html document you got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
<meta content="max-age=0" http-equiv="cache-control">
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="cache-control"/>
<meta content="0" http-equiv="expires"/>
<meta content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" http-equiv="expires"/>
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="pragma"/>
<meta content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=996b9d94-b538-4e4f-9afe-67434911be37&amp;httpReferrer=%2Fkeira-office-chair-cloud-grey-and-copper" http-equiv="refresh"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(window){
                try {
                        if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
                                sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
                        }
                } catch (e){}
        })(window);
</script>
<script defer="" src="/jyqoxgnrwlzilgpz.js" type="text/javascript"></script><style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#szabqxaftfdvevsqbsbcubrbzcuffvaw{display:none!important}</style></meta></head>
<body>
<div id="distilIdentificationBlock"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It looks like the website is using a bot blocker...since this was just a proof of concept I shall decide on another website to practice on. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! :D